# How to determine the load requirement for a 24 VDC power supply

Tags: power-supply, dc, load

I work in the automotive industry. I got a project to add extra hardware to a particular line. The current hardware requires 24 V, 70 W.

We have a power supply unit "Power One HE-24V-7.2A" in the cabinet, to which "n" number of sensors, limit switches, grippers, power supplies for IO modules of PLC, etc. are connected.

I couldn't find exactly what all the devices are that are connected to the 24 V power supply, but a lot of sensors. I don't have any document to check the load requirement of this particular line.

The only thing I can see is that the output of the power supply is connected to an 8 A fuse.

By considering this I'm thinking the load requirement of this line might be 24 V · 8 A = 200 W approx.
Is this 200W the load requirement of the line?

If I add extra hardware (24 V, 70 W) to this power supply, will my power ratings and voltage ratings differ? Could someone explain to me exactly how to deal with this?

Comment: 8A is an upper bound, certainly. It could be less than 8A but with that fuse it won't be more than 8A.

Comment: So my total current would be less than 8A for all the sensor and switches whatever are connected to this power supply right? so does it make any difference if I connect a hardware which takes 3A.

Comment: As long as the total current is less than the power supply's rated current (which it looks like is probably 7.2A), you should be fine. The fuse won't blow until you hit 8A, but the power supply won't be happy at that current, and might not provide 24V.

Comment: Calculate (or measure) the current from the existing PSU to the existing load. 24V 70W means you need 3A additional, so if the PSU is currently supplying less than 4A of its 7.2A rating it should be able to drive the extra load (if it's properly cooled and fed from an adequate source etc etc)

Comment: Power is never a particularly meaningful unit here. Only (peak) current matters. One needs to sum the current draw of everything connected, no way around it.

Answer (score 0):

The fuse is redundant for the supply you chose which already has active OVP and OCP, but may have been useful for a much bigger previous supply.   You may wish to add decoupling caps to end device loads if you suspect inductive noise currents.  Sensors in particular may be prone to shared  conduction noise with solenoid or motors. Otherwise cable wiring needs to consider ambient noise for compatibility (EMC) and possibly require shielded STP cables grounded only at source.

I don’t see any PSU issues but choice of earth grounding to 0Vdc must be based on noise immunity (EMC) requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "load requirement". The only "requirement" that I know of, is that whatever current you draw from this power supply must not exceed 7.2A, according to the datasheet. Not 8A, as you seem to have assumed.

Each devices will either have a certain power rating, in Watts (W), or a certain "maximum current" rating, in Amperes (A). We can either work in units of power (W) or current (A), just be consistent.

Using the power formula \$P=I\times V\$ it's easy to convert between them, considering that the voltage is known in all cases to be 24V. For example, if you have a module that is rated 100mA, the power that it consumes is:

$$ P = I \times V = 24V \times 0.1A = 2.4W $$

Likewise, if the module has a power rating of 12W, the current it will draw will be:

$$ I = \frac{P}{V} = \frac{12W}{24V} = 0.5A $$

If you decide to work in terms of current, then the sum of all the current requirements of all the modules must not exceed the maximum current this power supply can source:

$$ I_{MAX} =  \frac{P_{MAX}}{V} = \frac{172W}{24V} = 7.2A $$

If you are working with power, the sum of the power requirements of all modules must not exceed  the maximum power that the power supply can provide, which in your case is:

$$ P_{MAX} = I_{MAX} \times V = 7.2A \times 24V = 172W $$

As you can see, the two are equivalent. Since the voltage across all the modules is constant at 24V, it's just a question of converting between current and power as required, so that you can add them all up to arrive at a total, and then ensuring that this total does not exceed the power supply's ability.

If I have a number of modules, some rated with a certain power, others in Amperes of current, I would just convert everything to current, and add them all up:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdc9vp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The total current drawn by all modules here is 4.6A, which the power supply would have no problem with. Just don't exceed 7.2A total.

In terms of power, as calculated before, the maximum power that you can obtain from this supply \$P_{MAX} = 172W\$. Let's say you intend to add an extra load of \$P_{ADD}=70W\$ onto the supply, and the existing load is \$P_{NOW}\$. You must ensure that total power demand does not exceed \$P_{MAX}\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{NOW} + P_{ADD} &\le P_{MAX} \\ \\
P_{NOW} + 70W &\le 172W \\ \\
P_{NOW} &\le 172W - 70W \\ \\
P_{NOW} &\le 102W \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$